# Error : panel1 does not exist in correct context

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I resolve this error.

my code is

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView" runat="server" Style="position: relative; left: 299px; top: 69px;" PageSize="5" OnRowCommand="gridView_OnRowCommand" AllowPaging="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridView_SelectedIndexChan ged1" >

<PagerTemplate>
<% if (gridView.PageIndex > 0) 
{ %>
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnPrevious" runat="server" Style="vertical-align: middle;" ImageUrl="pre.jpg" OnClick="click1" 
CommandArgument="Prev" CommandName="Page" /> 

<% } %> 

<%=(gridView.PageIndex * 5) + 1%> <%=(gridView.PageIndex * 5) + gridView.Rows.Count%> 
<% if (gridView.PageIndex != (gridView.PageCount - 1)) 
{ %> 



<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnNext" runat="server" Style="vertical-align: middle;" ImageUrl="next.jpg" OnClick="click" CommandArgument="Next" CommandName="Page" /> 
<% } %> 

<%--<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnNext" runat="server"
Style="vertical-align: middle;" ImageUrl="next.jpg" 
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Next")%>' OnClick="click" CommandName="Page" />--%>
</PagerTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
</aspanel>
<%--<%=(gridView.PageIndex * 5) + 1%> <%=(gridView.PageIndex * 5) + gridView.Rows.Count%> --%> 
<% if (gridView.PageIndex != (gridView.PageCount - 1)) 
{ %> 



<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnNext" runat="server" Style="vertical-align: middle;" ImageUrl="next.jpg" OnClick="click" CommandArgument="Next" CommandName="Page" /> 
<% } %> 

<%--<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnNext" runat="server"
Style="vertical-align: middle;" ImageUrl="next.jpg" 
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Next")%>' OnClick="click" CommandName="Page" />--%>
</PagerTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

and code behind is

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adapPaging = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from customer", "Data Source=OPWFMS-7KYGZ7SB;Initial Catalog=Mayank;User ID=sa;Password=sa");
        adapPaging.Fill(ds);

        gridView.DataSource = ds;
        gridView.DataBind();
    }

    public void click1(object send, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewPageEventArgs obj = new GridViewPageEventArgs(gridView.PageIndex - 1);

        gridView.PageIndex = obj.NewPageIndex;

        LinkButton exmp = new LinkButton();
        exmp.Text = "exmp";
        Panel1.Controls.Add(exmp);
    }

    public void click(object send, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewPageEventArgs obj = new GridViewPageEventArgs(gridView.PageIndex+1);

        gridView.PageIndex = obj.NewPageIndex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing `Panel1` but it's not declared anywhere in the code you've provided.

Is there some other code you've not shown?

If not then the error is simply down to the fact that you haven't declared `Panel1`.